# How to Define Model in Native Pytorch Format and Import Into LightningModule Without Copy and Pasting?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Let's say I have a native pytorch model like this

```
class NormalAutoEncoder(nn.Module)):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(28 * 28, 64), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(64, 3))
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3, 64), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(64, 28 * 28))

    def forward(self, x):
        # in lightning, forward defines the prediction/inference actions
        embedding = self.encoder(x)
        return embedding
```

How can I have the `__init__` and `forward` functions (basically, the whole network) into a pytorch lighting module without copying and pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Make use of Python's inheritance mechanism.

If the following is a native PyTorch module

```
class NormalAutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = ...
        self.decoder = ...

    def forward(self, x):
        embedding = ...
        return embedding
```

Then have your new `LightningAutoEncoder` that *also* inherits from `NormalAutoEncoder`

```
class LightningAutoEncoder(LightningModule, NormalAutoEncoder):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        LightningModule.__init__(self) # only LightningModule's init
        NormalAutoEncoder.__init__(self, ...) # this basically executes __init__() of the NormalAutoEncoder

    def forward(self, x):
        # offloads its execution to NormalAutoEncoder's forward() method
        return NormalAutoEncoder.forward(self, x)
```

That's it. No copy-pasting.

Comment: Great solution! However, is there anyway to do this without passing in the NormalAutoEncoder Class as a function argument?

Comment: Its not *function argument*, its inheritance.
What exactly is your requirement ? Why would you not want to inherit ? In that case, you can just create a `NormalAutoEncoder` instance as a attribute to the Lightning class.